# Dropping rows in a dataframe

Tags: python-2.7

Suppose we have this dataframe:

```
a = [["1", "2"], ["1", "3"], ["2", "1"]]
data = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=["one", "two"])
```

I need a result like:

```
a = [["1", "2"], ["1", "3"]]
```

My question is how to drop this row (the third row)? Because here these two rows (first and third) are not the same but they have the same values in different columns.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain more clearly what your problem is. I presume the naive `a=a[0:2]` is not what you're looking for, but what is `pd` and what logic do you want to apply for filtering?

Comment: pd is: 
import pandas as pd.